# R SQL Update statement with Inner Join

Tags: sql, r, join

The below SQL statement works in Microsoft Access but not in R when using SQLDF.  I believe it is because SQLDF is SQLite and that doesn't support joins in update statements.  Problem is, I don't know how to get around the issue.
How do I accomplish the below update in R?

```
    UPDATE NewData INNER JOIN Inforce ON NewData.ContractNumber = Inforce.PolicyNumber SET Inforce.IncomeRider = "N" WHERE (((NewData.[Rider Termination Date])<=[Inforce].[FileDate]));
```

I tried in R:

```
sqldf('UPDATE NewData INNER JOIN Inforce ON NewData.ContractNumber = Inforce.PolicyNumber SET Inforce.IncomeRider = "Y" WHERE ((NewData.[Rider Termination Date])>[Inforce].[FileDate])')
```

And received this error:

> Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
>     error in statement: near "INNER": syntax error

This doesn't have to be accomplished by a SQL statement but thought it would be easiest for me since I already had a working SQL statement.

```
NewData <- data.frame(ContractNumber=c(1,2,3),
                      RiderTerminationDate=c(as.Date(c("2015-01-01","2015-06-01","2016-05-01"))))

Inforce <- data.frame(PolicyNumber=c(1,2,3,4),
                      IncomeRider=c('Y','N','N','N'),
                      FileDate=c(as.Date(c("2014-01-01","2013-01-01","2016-08-01","2016-02-01"))))
```

Resulting IncomeRider should be 'Y','N','Y','N'

Comment: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#1-how-does-sqldf-handle-classes-and-factors Check Question #8 .

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I understand what you are saying but I didn't think you would need to reproduce my data and run my query.  I was hoping that someone could just see the error in my logic and provide another option to my issue instead of sqldf.  Thanks

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Code added for reproducing.  Thanks!

Comment: `fileDate` only has 3 elements whereas the other columns have 4 so it gives an error.  Also 2014-01-01 is not a date.  It means 2014 minus 1 minus 1.  Maybe you mean `fileDate = c("2014-01-01", ...)`  a vector of character strings, or `fileDate = c(as.Date(c("2014-01-01", ...)))`, a vector of Dates.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks for sticking with me, still new and learning.  Anyway, I have updated the columns as you indicated so I hope they are good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. One line of code in the question sets `IncomeRider` to 'N' and another to 'Y'.  We assume you meant 'Y'.
2. sqlite does not support joins in `update` (but it does support correlated subqueries).  For the syntax of `update` in sqlite see:  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html
3. The code shown in the question is trying to update NewData but IncomeRider is a column in Inforce, not NewData.
4. update does not return a result -- it only performs an update of the table in sqlite -- so a select is needed in the sqldf argument to return something.

Addressing these we have:

```
sqldf(c("update Inforce
         set IncomeRider = 'Y' 
         where fileDate >= (select n.RiderTerminationDate 
                            from NewData n
                            where n.ContractNumber = Inforce.PolicyNumber)",
         "select * from Inforce"))
```

giving:

```
  PolicyNumber IncomeRider   FileDate
1            1           Y 2014-01-01
2            2           N 2013-01-01
3            3           Y 2016-08-01
4            4           N 2016-02-01
```

The sqldf statement returns the updated `Inforce` but you still have to assign that to `Infoce` or some other variable: `Inforce_updated <- sqldf(...)`

**2)** The poster of the question also posted an answer although it gives a different result than asked for in the question.  In that answer instead of performing an update to a subset of rows in Inforce a merged data frame is returned in which the existing IncomeRider column is completely ignored and it is set to N unless the required condition is satisfied.  If that is what is wanted then try this:

```
sqldf("select PolicyNumber, 
              case when RiderTerminationDate is null or 
                        FileDate >= RiderTerminationDate 
              then
                   'N'
              else 
                   'Y'
              end IncomeRider,
              FileDate,
              RiderTerminationDate
       from Inforce 
       left join NewData on ContractNumber = PolicyNumber")
```

giving:

```
  PolicyNumber IncomeRider   FileDate RiderTerminationDate
1            1           Y 2014-01-01           2015-01-01
2            2           Y 2013-01-01           2015-06-01
3            3           N 2016-08-01           2016-05-01
4            4           N 2016-02-01                 <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be you should use this sintax

```
  UPDATE NewData 
  SET  Inforce.IncomeRider = "Y" 
  FROM NewData 
  INNER JOIN Inforce ON NewData.ContractNumber = Inforce.PolicyNumber 
  WHERE ((NewData.[Rider Termination Date])>[Inforce].[FileDate])
```

or using alias

```
  UPDATE ti 
  SET  Inforce.IncomeRider = "Y" 
  FROM NewData as t1
  INNER JOIN Inforce ON t1.ContractNumber = Inforce.PolicyNumber 
  WHERE ((t1.[Rider Termination Date])>[Inforce].[FileDate])
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to review the above answers yet (but I will).  I have found a different solution to my problem.  I changed the column name in NewData from ContractNumber to PolicyNumber then merged the 2 dataframes together and updated the IncomeRider field.

```
MergedData = merge(Inforce,NewData,by = 'PolicyNumber',all.x = TRUE)

# Update Transactions.IBR with 'Y' where NewData.RiderTermination > Transactions.FileDate
MergedData$IncomeRider[MergedData$RiderTerminationDate > MergedData$FileDate] <- "Y"

# Update Transactions.IBR with 'N' where NewData.RiderTermination <= Transactions.FileDate
MergedData$IncomeRider[MergedData$RiderTerminationDate <= MergedData$FileDate] <- "N"

# Update IBR with 'N' where Newdata.RiderTermination is NA
MergedData$IncomeRider[is.na(MergedData$RiderTerminationDate)] <- "N"
```

Comment: This gives YYNN but the question says the answer is YNYN.  Also this answer is not consistent with what the question asks as it sets every IncomeRider whereas the code in the question only sets some of the IncomeRider rows.